# constants in Swift not really constant?

Tags: swift, variables, constants

I just started to learn Swift 3. I am a little bit experienced in C++ but I am a bit confused when it comes to constants in Swift.

Following code:

```
class Auto {

    var maxKmH:Int = 50;
    var color:String = "green";
}


class Autohaus
{
    public var Autos:[Auto] = [];
    let amount:Int;

    func addAutos()
    {
        for i in 0..<self.amount{
            var car = Auto(); // warning to replace VAR with LET ???
            Autos.append(car);
        }
    }
}
```

So Xcode advises me to use **let** instead of **var** in the following line

```
var car = Auto();
```

When I do that, the warning disappears HOWEVER I can still change the object (for example the attributes).

This confuses me a bit, since a constant actually can be changed? Why do I need let then, if it's mutable?

Thanks guys!

Comment: If you changed `Auto` from being a `class` to a `struct`, you'd get the desired behaviour of immutability with `let`.

Comment: Also note that you don't need semicolons at the end of statements, property and variable names should be `lowerCamelCase`, and you don't have to give explicit type annotations on declarations where the compiler can infer the type (e.g `var color = "green"`).

Comment: Thank you very much @Hamish for linking the other thread. I was reading it and I get it now! The only thing I am wondering, is what is in my case the benefit of using let instead of var, since I can (and want) to edit my attributes anyway? Is there in general a benefit of using let instead of var for objects of classes? The only benefit I see, is telling my Array of class Autohaus, that I don't want to change the objects (reference).

Comment: and thanks for the other advices :)

Comment: Using `let` lets you communicate that you don't intend for a given value to change – as you say, this is still applicable for reference types, as you won't be able to change the reference to a class instance if you annotate it as a `let`. Besides this, it also allows the compiler to perform various optimisations with the knowledge that a given value cannot change.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hamish, that make sense! I have one last question:

Is there a better way to do this:

            var car = Auto();
            Autos.append(car);

Because it seems like I waste memory for creating a variable and then put it  in an array anyway. Wouldn't it be better if I could do something like: 
            Autos.append(Auto()); 
Because it seems that I don't waste extra memory for a var which will be copied anyway into the array.

Comment: oh and I would like to mark it as good answers, but unfortunately I can't do it with a comment :)

Comment: No problem :) I don't believe it will make a difference (memory wise) doing `let car = Auto(); autos.append(car)` vs. `autos.append(Auto())`. I believe both will allocate stack space for the reference caller-side, although I could be wrong. In any case, the only extra cost would be a reference on the stack, which is trivial. Simply choose the option that you find the most readable.